# Question on the no existence of limit sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If I have a sequence and **by assumption is surely not convergent**, in order to determine if it does not admit limit or it is divergent I have thought that:

This means that surely if the overall sequence was divergent I should have that the two subsequence diverge equally (I mean both to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$).

**Question:** if I have $a_{2n}$ decreasing and $a_{2}>0$ and $a_{2n+1}$ increasing and $a_{1}<0$ it is possible that both of them diverge equally?
If not this prove that my sequence does not admit limit, right?

I have considered only the possibility of infinite limits since as matter of fact if the limit of the two subsequence was finite these limits cannot coincide because I know by hypothesis that my overall sequence does not admit limit. Is it a right observation?

Comment: you mean like $a_{2n}=3-2n$ and $a_{2n+1}=-1+2n$?

Comment: I see no reason why your sequence as you have described it can't be convergent.

Comment: Nope sorry maybe I have not explained my doubt clearly! I suppose that i am dealing with a sequence surely not convergent a then I want to prove if it is divergent or it has no limit

Comment: I have confused your example