# Limit of increasing and decreasing sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

With reference to [Previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4144898/879543) I want to understand if it possible that a sequence that is decreasing and with an positive initial value can diverge to $+\infty$. I think no since its limit can be only or a number or it is $-\infty$. 
With the same idea an increasing sequence with a negative initial value cannot diverge to $-\infty$.
So surely if this two subsequences are divergent their limit is different $(-\infty\neq +\infty)$.

What do you think about?

Comment: First thing is think about the what is the definition of a sequence diverging to minus infinity.Do you see you get a contradiction?

Comment: $\forall M>0$ I have $a_n<-M \forall n\geq \bar{n}$?

Comment: @Shashank I mean do you think my idea explained in the question is correct? And so if two subsequence are one increasing and the other decreasing then surely they cannot diverge equally (regardeless their initial point)?

Comment: Your argument is fine - any decreasing sequence, but regardless of its first term, cannot diverge to $+\infty$ and either converges to a  finite limit or diverges to $-\infty$.  Likewise an increasing sequence, also regardless of its first term, must converge to a finite limit or diverge to $+\infty$.

Comment: @WaDon Thanks a lot is what I wanted to know in order to solve my previous question! I would like to give you a $+1$ but in comments is not possible! :)